# How to edit email preview text for emails in magento 2 when using header template

Tags: email, magento, html-email, magento2

I am working on customizing emails in Magento 2 admin panel. I have created a header template and footer template, and have also created other email templates that pull the header and footer from the previously mentioned templates. We have tested the emails, and noticed that the email preview text pulls the words from the header first, then the body of the email. Instead, we want to just show the body of the email as the preview text.

In order to do this, we can add a div with the preview text we want shown, before the header. But, because of the various different email templates, we would want the preview text to be specific for each email template. Since the preview text div needs to be added in the header template, I'm not sure how to customize it so it is different for each email template, when they are all pulling from the same header template.

```
<div style="display:none;font-size:1px;color:#ffffff;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden">Hello {{customerFirstname}}, Your claim concerning order {{orderUuid}} for the following item: Item name: {{productTitle}} Item status: {{offerState}} Item price: {{priceUnit}} Quantity: {{quantity}}</div>
```

So, in order to easily change the email header in the future, we need to keep the email header template in place. Is there a way to customize the preview text to show the body text of each email, instead of showing the words from the header?

We want the email preview to look like the red example, not including the header text words of "Dairy Protein Dry Goods and Non-Food"

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't use Magento but if you define a merge tag/token you might be able to make the preview text dynamic. The only thing is you will need to remember to pass it thru each time.

Comment: Been a while since I've worked on Magento 2 but it may be a case of adding custom fields? I've done it for products, to show custom information that our client's product data didn't fit into the default fields provided by Magento. BUT to be honest I'm not sure how you could do this for the email functionality out of Magento.

Comment: I would research how you can add custom fields or the like, to the email tool in Magento 2. That may point you in the right direction. I would also post this exact question in the Magento Stack Exchange - https://magento.stackexchange.com/